Segmentaiton fault or Trap in pyobjc keyboard hook
I'm trying to write a small application for macOS in Python where opening characters such as [ { ( < " ' are paired/closed automatically (similar to how it's handled in editors like VS Code, but globally).
I'm using pyobjc to set up a keyboard hook. So far I've been able to get the hook callback to fire once (e.g., when I type < the callback fires and adds >) before hitting either...
a segmentation fault
zsh: segmentation fault  /<project path>/.venv/bin/python

or trace trap
zsh: trace trap  /<project path>/.venv/bin/python

I'm not sure what's causing either, and the error I get isn't always the same (it's most often the TRAP, but sometimes SEGV)
Here's my working example:
import Quartz as qz
from AppKit import NSEvent
from time import sleep

PAIRS = {
    '\'': '\'',
    '"': '"',
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
    '<': '>',
    '`': '`',
}


def is_synthetic_event(event: qz.CGEventRef) -> bool:
    """Check if the event is synthetic"""
    source_state = qz.CGEventGetIntegerValueField(
        event,
        qz.kCGEventSourceStateID
    )
    # NOTE: seems like this is always 1...
    print(f'Event Source State: {source_state}')  # DEBUG
    return source_state == qz.kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState


def kbd_callback(
    _proxy: object,
    _event_type: int,
    event: qz.CGEventRef,
    _refcon: object
) -> qz.CGEventRef:
    """Intercept key press events"""
    try:
        # convert to NSEvent to access character information
        key_event = NSEvent.eventWithCGEvent_(event)
        print(key_event)  # DEBUG
        repeat = key_event.isARepeat()
        # skip synthetic events to prevent recursion
        # NOTE: this is not working as expected - negation is wrong, but
        # the calback doesn't fire without it
        if not is_synthetic_event(event):
            return event
        # check if the character matches an opening pair
        if (char := key_event.characters()) in PAIRS and not repeat:
            # post the opening character
            qz.CGEventPost(qz.kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, event)
            sleep(0.01)
            closing_char = PAIRS[char]
            # create and post a key down event for the closing character
            press_event = qz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0, True)
            qz.CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(press_event, 1, closing_char)
            qz.CGEventPost(qz.kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, press_event)
            qz.CFRelease(press_event)
            # give the system time to process the event
            sleep(0.01)
            # create and post a key release event for the closing character
            release_event = qz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0, False)
            qz.CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(release_event, 1, closing_char)
            qz.CGEventPost(qz.kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, release_event)
            qz.CFRelease(release_event)
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Error in callback: {err}')
    return event


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # create a global event tap
        event_tap = qz.CGEventTapCreate(
            qz.kCGSessionEventTap,  # tap location
            qz.kCGHeadInsertEventTap,  # insert at head of event queue
            qz.kCGEventTapOptionDefault,  # read-write access
            qz.CGEventMaskBit(qz.kCGEventKeyDown),  # key-down events only
            kbd_callback,  # callback function
            None  # no user data
        )

        if event_tap:
            loop_source = qz.CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(None, event_tap, 0)
            qz.CFRunLoopAddSource(
                qz.CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                loop_source,
                qz.kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
            )
            qz.CGEventTapEnable(event_tap, True)
            qz.CFRunLoopRun()
        else:
            print('Failed to create event tap')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Error in main: {err}')

I suspect this is related to the synthetic events triggering the callback, but I'm not sure. I've also found that my is_synthetic_event function doesn't work as expected. I have to invert it or the callback doesn't fire at all.
Any help is welcome! I'm quite comfortable in Python, but much less so with pyobjc.

@willeke That helped, thank you. I'm still not 100% sure what I was doing wrong, but I was able to adapt that answer to my problem.
